Ubuntu 24.04 boot up stuck after installing and using apfs-fuse
I installed apfs-fuse to access external drive from an old mac. After struggling a little bit (I'm really a neebie with linux...), it worked nice ... until screen was locked, I was then unable to start session again, could only reboot the computer.
On restart, boot was stuck with some strange message about bluetooth (which is probably not relevant, just consequence of the boot problem). I've mostly asked chatgpt for help, used recovery mode and found out that /etc/fstab looked wrong (missing the UUID names). I corrected it manually, it seems that boot now goes further.
But it still stops with another error message fsckd-cancel-msg: press Ctrl+C to cancel all verification on file system. Ctrl+C has no effect. I tried the option of recovery mode about fsck, no results. I tried something manually but got e2fsck: cannot continue, immediate stop.
With root mode (recovery) I can mount partitions and see content normally, but something remains wrong during the boot. I'm totally lost, I don't know what to do

keep on trying to solve problems little by little? (wihtout really know what I'm doing, always feeling like I'll make it worst...)
reinstall ubuntu with boot disk?
and if I manage to start again normally, what should I do about apfs-fuse (because I need to follow this path to recover data on external drive)

let's hope someone can understand and help.
I found a similar post, but not sure that it is exactly the same problem/solution. I understand it suggest removing apfs-fuse and reinstalling gdm3. There is another proposition (without uninstalling apfs-fuse) that simply install ubuntu-desktop again.
which option would you suggest?

rem out the offending line in fstab and see if that boots cleanly and then research from there.

Merci. What would be this offending line? how to identify it? there is actually 4 lines: 1. uuid with / ext4 defaults 0 1, 2. uuid /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 2, 3. uuid partition données ext4 0 2 4. /swap.img none swap sw 0 0

impossible to say without knowing what your fstab consists of. You'd perhaps get a clue by using the try Ubuntu option and looking at the /etc/fstab file there as it will be in it's simplest form to enable the iso to run.

thanks again for your reply. So I rebooted with USB and try UBUNTU live. Worked well. /etc/fstab is totally diferent from the one I have (see previous message): 1. overlay / overlay rw 0 0 2. tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0 . Am i supposed to copy this?? also strange thing (for me...) i've noticed, the dedicated partition for ubuntu is mounted diferently. was on / but now in live it's /media/ubuntu/xxxxxxx-xxx..., being xxxxxxx-xxx... the uuid for / in the /etc/fstab. is that normal or also something I should change in etc/fstab ?? @graham

the idea of looking at the live session fstab was to give you some clues as to what might be missing/wrong with your amended one. Maybe you should just start over and this time carefully research any changes you propose before committing them?

ok, by start over you mean reinstall ubuntu, no? and by carrefully research any changes you refer to installing apfs-use?

yes, that about sums it up. That's what you asked in your original question and I agree with you.

thanks for your support and advise!

last bit of advice - keep copious notes of what you do to help in unravelling any issues (and as a future reference for subsequent installations).

The problem was solved thanks to:

After installation of fuse2 Ubuntu boot up stuck

Ubuntu 23.04 does not boot after installing "fuse"


The solution was:
systemctl start NetworkManager
apt install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot

sudo reboot worked fine, but no installed application is working, not even the App Center, and I'm not able to activate Bluetooth. I guess I need to get rid of fuse and really reinstall.
